# How to randomly select data from one array to another and avoiding duplicate

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to randomly select array values on another array avoiding duplicate but am getting an output that is out of my scope.

please help.

Here is my code below

```
 static Random rn = new Random();

 static void RandomGenerator()
 {
     String[] greatingsStyles = { "Hello", "Hay", "Morning", "Good day", "Howzit", "Sure" };
     String[] newGreatingsStyles = { };
     for (int j = 0; greatingsStyles.Length >j; j++)
     {
         String ranGreatingsStyles = greatingsStyles[rn.Next(5)];
         if (!greatingsStyles.Contains(ranGreatingsStyles))
         {
             newGreatingsStyles = newGreatingsStyles.Concat(new string[] { ranGreatingsStyles }).ToArray();
         }
     }
     foreach (int i in newGreatingsStyles.ToString())
     {
         Console.WriteLine(i);
     }
}
```

Comment: What output you are getting? What is your scope?

Comment: shuffle and gen n first ...

Comment: It sounds like a school assignment. So don't know if you can use this. I would shuffle the list and return the result. Take a look at the following StackOverFlow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt

Comment: Why it has +1 ? question was already asked multiple times

Comment: Does `newGreatingsStyles` should contains all items of `newGreatingsStyles`?